# Draw and erase arcs - Arc animation using JavaScript or CSS

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, svg, html5-canvas

I have a case where I want to draw 3 arc lines and erase them.

[image]

First Arc CA should be drawn progressively and then it should be erased progressively. Then arc AB should be drawn and erased and then arc BC should do the same. And then repeat.

**My approach:**

**Using canvas and JS:**

I started with canvas, but the anti-aliasing does not effect here. So I thought may be SVG will be better.

```js
   var currentEndAngle = 0;
   var currentStartAngle = 0;
   var currentColor = 'black';
   var lineRadius = 300;
   var lineWidth = 5;

   setInterval(draw, 5);

   function draw() { 

       var can = document.getElementById('canvas1'); // GET LE CANVAS
       var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
       var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
       var x = canvas.width / 2;
       var y = canvas.height / 2;
       var radius;
       var width;

       var startAngle = currentStartAngle * Math.PI;
       var endAngle = (currentEndAngle) * Math.PI;
       
       currentStartAngle = currentEndAngle - 0.01;
       currentEndAngle = currentEndAngle + 0.01;
       
       if (Math.floor(currentStartAngle / 2) % 2) {
         currentColor = "white";
         radius = lineRadius - 1;
         width = lineWidth + 3;
       } else {
         currentColor = "black";
         radius = lineRadius;
         width = lineWidth;
       }
               
       var counterClockwise = false;

       context.beginPath();
       context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, counterClockwise);
       context.lineWidth = width;
       // line color
       context.strokeStyle = currentColor;
       context.stroke();

       /************************************************/
   }
```

```css
            body {
    text-align: center;
                background: blue;
   } 
   #canvas1 {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
   }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas1" width="700" height="700"></canvas>
```

**Using SVG and CSS**

The SVG approach looks smoother. But I don't understand how I can modify the dasharray, dashoffset and radius of circle to get 3 arcs animating.

```css
 circle {
   fill: transparent;
   stroke: black;
   stroke-width: 2;
   stroke-dasharray: 250;
   stroke-dashoffset: 0;
   animation: rotate 5s linear infinite;
 }

 @keyframes rotate {
   0% {
     stroke-dashoffset: 500;
   }
   100% {
     stroke-dashoffset: 0;
   }
 }
```

```html
<svg height="400" width="400">
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="40" />
</svg>
```

So if anyone can help me extend the code or give guidance on how I can create three arcs from the svg circle and how the dasharray, dashoffset and radius should be set?

In case you have a better solution then the above 2 approaches then please let me know.

I have also tried to use the drawsvg plugin from GSAP and I guess that might be easier but I am not allowed to use the 'drawsvg' plugin for my project.

Comment: The canvas thing is find, you just need to call context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); to fix the aliasing problem, right now it's drawing the same parts over and over, although to be honest I think if you find a way to fix the svg solution it would be a cleaner approach imho (I can't help you there because I haven't really understood what the end result should be)

Comment: Thanks @JonasGiuro. The expected result is similar to what you see above for the svg demo. But currently the entire circle is drawn and then erased. What I expect is to draw 0 to 0.75*PI first and then erase it and then draw 0.75*PI to 1.25*PI and then erase it and then draw 1.25*PI to 2*PI and then erase it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the canvas version, as stated in comments, your antialiasing problem is that you are redrawing over and over on the same pixels.

To avoid this, clear your whole canvas every frame and redraw everything.

---

For your requested animation, you would have to store both your start angle and your end angle. Then you'll increment one after the other, while swithing when you've passed the division size threshold.

Here is an annotated snippet that will make things more clear I hope.

```js
// settings
var divisions = 3;
var duration = 3000; // in ms
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var x = canvas.width / 2;
var y = canvas.height / 2;
var radius = (canvas.width / 7) * 2;
context.lineWidth = 4;

// init
var currentSplit = 0;
var splitAngle = (Math.PI * 2) / divisions;
var splitTime = (duration / (divisions*2)); // how much time per split per end
var angles = [0,0]; // here we store both start and end angle
var current = 0;
var startTime = performance.now();
draw();

function draw(currentTime) {
  // first convert the elapsed time to an angle
  var timedAngle =  ((currentTime - startTime) / splitTime) * splitAngle;
  // set the current end to this timed angle + the current position on the circle
  angles[current] = timedAngle + (splitAngle * currentSplit);

  if (timedAngle >= splitAngle) {  // one split is done for this end
    // it should not go farther than the threshold
    angles[current] = (splitAngle * (currentSplit + 1));
    current = +(!current) // switch which end should move
    startTime = currentTime; // reset the timer

    if(!current){ // we go back to the start
      currentSplit = (currentSplit + 1) % divisions; // increment our split index
      }
  }

  if(angles[1] > Math.PI*2){ // we finished one complete revolution
    angles[0] = angles[1] = current = 0; // reset everything
    }
  
  // at every frame we clear everything
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  // and redraw
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, radius, angles[0], angles[1], true);
  context.stroke();

  requestAnimationFrame(draw); // loop at screen refresh rate
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

#canvas1 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas1" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Kalido for the solution. I tried both SVG and canvas. Finally used the canvas solution for my project. But I must say the solution with SVG is cool too.

Answer (score 3):

You don't really want to modify `stroke-dashoffset`, because that just shifts the dash patter around the circle.

You have to modify the dash array values anyway, so you might as well just do it all by animating the values in the dash array.

Your circle has radius 40, so the circumference is 251.33.  Meaning that each of your three arc has a length of 83.78.

For each of the three stages, we grow the "on" part of the dash from 0 to 83.78.  Then we shrink it back down again, while simultaneously growing the previous gap from 83.78 to 167.55. That is so that the tail gets pushed around to the end.

That works for the first two steps, but since the dash pattern starts and ends at the 3 o'clock position (and doesn't wrap through that point), we have to do the tail push for the last stage by using an extra empty dash pair at the start. We grow the gap on that one from 0 to 83.78 instead.

```css
circle {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2;
  animation: rotate 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0%    { stroke-dasharray: 0 0      0     83.78   0     83.78   0     83.78; }
  16.7% { stroke-dasharray: 0 0      0     83.78  83.78   0      0     83.78; }
  33.3% { stroke-dasharray: 0 0      0    167.55   0      0      0     83.78; }
  50%   { stroke-dasharray: 0 0      0     83.78   0     83.78  83.78   0;    }
  66.6% { stroke-dasharray: 0 0      0     83.78   0    167.55   0      0;    }
  83.3% { stroke-dasharray: 0 0     83.78   0      0     83.78   0     83.78; }
  100%  { stroke-dasharray: 0 83.78  0      0      0     83.78   0     83.78; }
}
```

```html
<svg height="400" width="400">
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="40" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Paul for the solution. I learnt a lot. The only reason I am accepting the canvas answer is because, that's what I implemented on my project. Otherwise both SVG and Canvas are great and I tried both of them.

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript extends HTML

Canvas, (or CSS, HTML, SVG) combined with javascript always wins out over CSS, SVG, HTML alone because Javascript is far more adaptable. HTML, CSS and SVG are declarative languages, while JavaScript is a fully functional imperative language that can do anything any other programing language can do.

You use javascript to add to the HTML, CSS, SVG functionality, effectively declaring new behaviour for these languages.

Once you have defined the Javascript functionality you can forget about the javascript and use the HTML, CSS, or SVG calling upon the new behaviours as needed.

In this case all elements with the class name `"segmentedProgress"` will become an animated progress. You can set up as many properties as you like to control the behaviour and add them to the element's data attribute.

eg

```
<div class="segmentedProgress"></div>
<!-- showing defaults as above element will be setup -->
<div class="segmentedProgress" 
      data-angle-steps = 3      <!-- number of segments. (integers only) -->
      data-speed = 1000         <!-- Time per segment in ms -->
      data-easing = "1.2"       <!-- easing power -->
      data-line-width = "0.1"   <!-- as fraction of radius -->
      data-radial-size = "0.33" <!-- as fraction of shortest dimension -->
      data-color = "black"      <!-- colour of line -->
></div>
```

As long as the Javascript has been included the progress will automatically appear on the page for each element that is correctly configured. If you have your server setup to recognise page content dependencies then the above is all you need to do to add the behaviour to the page as the server will add what is needed to make it run.

#### The javascript

It does not take much javascript to implement. You find all the elements that have the appropriate class name and add them to an array of progress items. Then animate them as needed.

```
document.addEventListener("load", function(){
    var elements = [...document.body.querySelectorAll(".segmentedProgress")];
    if(elements.length === 0){  // exit if nothing found
        return;
    }
    // singleton to isolate from onload 
    (function(){
        const error = 0.01; // Math too perfect causes zero len arc to draw nothing. Error makes sure there is always some length in the drawn arc
        const items = [];  // array of progress items

        // each progress item defaults
        var defaults = {
            angleSteps : 3,  // number of segments. (integers only)
            speed : 1000,  // Time per segment in ms
            easing : 1.2, // easing power where 1 = no easing 2 = normal quadratic easing 1/2= inverse quadratic easing
            lineWidth : 0.1, // as fraction of radius
            radialSize : 0.33,// as fraction of shortest dimension
            color : "black",  // colour of line
            complete : false, // not used
            resize () { // resize the canvas and set size dependent vars
                this.bounds = this.element.getBoundingClientRect();
                this.w = this.canvas.width = this.bounds.width;
                this.h = this.canvas.height = this.bounds.height;
                this.canvas.style.top = (this.bounds.top + scrollY) + "px";  
                this.canvas.style.left = (this.bounds.left + scrollX) + "px";
                this.pos = { x : this.w / 2, y : this.h / 2}; // position of circle 
                this.radius = Math.min(this.w, this.h) * this.radialSize;    // radius of circle

                // set canvas state constants
                this.ctx.lineCap = "round";    
            },    
            update (time) { // updates and renders
                var segStart, segProgress, pp, ctx, ang;

                ctx = this.ctx; // alias to this.ctx

                // clear the canvas
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.w, this.h);

                // get current selment angle
                ang = Math.PI * 2 / this.angleSteps, // Radians per segment

                // set the time at the correct speed
                time /= this.speed;

                // get the segment start position in radians
                segStart = Math.floor(time % this.angleSteps) * ang;

                // get the unit progress of this stage doubled for grow and shrink stages
                var segProgress = (time % 1) * 2;
                var pp = segProgress % 1;  // pp partial progress
                pp = (pp ** this.easing) / ((pp ** this.easing) + (1 - pp) ** this.easing); // add some easing

                ctx.beginPath();

                // first half of progress is growth
                if(segProgress <= 1){
                    ctx.arc(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.radius, segStart, segStart + pp * ang + error);
                }else{
                    // second half of progress is shrink
                    ctx.arc(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.radius, segStart + pp * ang - error, segStart + ang);
                }
                ctx.strokeStyle = this.color;
                ctx.lineWidth  = this.radius * this.lineWidth;
                ctx.stroke();   
            }
        }

        // create prgress item for each found element
        elements.forEach(element => {
            var pItem = {...defaults}; // progress item
            pItem.element = element;
            // get any element setting that overwrite the defaults
            Object.keys(defaults).forEach(key => {
                if(typeof defaults[key] !== "function"){
                    if(element.dataset[key] !== undefined){
                        pItem[key] = element.dataset[key];
                        if(! isNaN(element.dataset[key])){
                            pItem[key] = Number(pItem[key]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            pItem.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            pItem.ctx = pItem.canvas.getContext("2d");
            pItem.canvas.style.position = "absolute";
            pItem.resize();
            items.push(pItem);
            element.appendChild(pItem.canvas);
        });
        elements.length = 0; // let go of elements

        // change size on resize
        window.addEventListener("resize", () =>{
            items.forEach(pItem => pItem.resize());
        });

        // start the animation
        requestAnimationFrame(update);    

        // main update loop
        function update (time) {
            items.forEach(pItem => {
                pItem.update(time);
            });
            requestAnimationFrame(update);                
        }
    }());
}());
```

#### As a demo

```js
//document.addEventListener("load",()=>{
;(function(){
    var elements = [...document.body.querySelectorAll(".segmentedProgress")];
    if (elements.length === 0) { return }
    (function () {
        const error = 0.001; // Math too perfect causes zero len arc to draw nothing. Error makes sure there is always some length in the drawn arc
        const items = [];  // array of progress items
        var defaults = {
            angleSteps : 3,  // number of segments. (integers only)
            speed : 1000,  // Time per segment in ms
            easing : 1.2, // easing power where 1 = no easing 2 = normal quadratic easing 1/2= inverse quadratic easing
            lineWidth : 0.1, // as fraction of radius
            radialSize : 0.33,// as fraction of shortest dimension
            color : "black",  // colour of line
            complete : false, // not used
            resize () { // resize the canvas and set size dependent vars
                this.bounds = this.element.getBoundingClientRect();
                this.w = this.canvas.width = this.bounds.width;
                this.h = this.canvas.height = this.bounds.height;
                this.canvas.style.top = (this.bounds.top + scrollY) + "px";  
                this.canvas.style.left = (this.bounds.left + scrollX) + "px";
                this.pos = { x : this.w / 2, y : this.h / 2}; // position of circle 
                this.radius = Math.min(this.w, this.h) * this.radialSize;    // radius of circle
                this.ctx.lineCap = "round";    
            },    
            update (time) { // updates and renders
                var segStart, segProgress, pp, ctx, ang;
                ctx = this.ctx; // alias to this.ctx
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.w, this.h);
                ang = Math.PI * 2 / this.angleSteps, // Radians per segment
                time /= this.speed;
                segStart = Math.floor(time % this.angleSteps) * ang;
                var segProgress = (time % 1) * 2;
                var pp = segProgress % 1;  // pp partial progress
                // babel can not handle the following line even though most
                // browsers can
                // pp = (pp ** this.easing) / ((pp ** this.easing) + (1 - pp) ** this.easing); // add some easing
                // to cover babel error
                pp = Math.pow(pp,this.easing) / (Math.pow(pp,this.easing) + Math.pow(1 - pp, this.easing)); // add some easing
                ctx.beginPath();
                if(segProgress <= 1){
                    ctx.arc(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.radius, segStart, segStart + pp * ang + error);
                }else{
                    ctx.arc(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.radius, segStart + pp * ang - error, segStart + ang);
                }
                ctx.strokeStyle = this.color;
                ctx.lineWidth  = this.radius * this.lineWidth;
                ctx.stroke();   
            }
        }
        elements.forEach(element => {
            var pItem = {...defaults}; // progress item
            pItem.element = element;
            Object.keys(defaults).forEach(key => {
                if(typeof defaults[key] !== "function"){
                    if(element.dataset[key] !== undefined){
                        pItem[key] = element.dataset[key];
                        if(! isNaN(element.dataset[key])){
                            pItem[key] = Number(pItem[key]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            pItem.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            pItem.ctx = pItem.canvas.getContext("2d");
            pItem.canvas.style.position = "absolute";
            pItem.resize();
            items.push(pItem);
            element.appendChild(pItem.canvas);
        });
        elements.length = 0; 
        window.addEventListener("resize", () =>{ items.forEach(pItem => pItem.resize()) });
        requestAnimationFrame(update);    
        function update (time) {
            items.forEach(pItem => { pItem.update(time) });
            requestAnimationFrame(update);                
        }
    }());
}());
```

```css
.segmentedProgress {
  width : 100px;
  height : 100px;
}
.big {
  width : 200px;
  height : 200px;
}
.large {
  width : 512px;
  height : 512px;
  background : #4AF;
}
```

```html
4 segment fast.
<div class="segmentedProgress" data-color="red" data-speed ="250" data-line-width="0.3" data-angle-steps=4   ></div>
Default Progress
<div class="segmentedProgress" ></div>
Big progress
<div class="big segmentedProgress" data-color="blue" data-speed ="2500" data-line-width="0.3" data-angle-steps=2  ></div>
60 Seconds two overlap

<div class="large segmentedProgress" data-color="white" data-speed ="1000" data-line-width="0.02" data-angle-steps=60  >
<div class="large segmentedProgress" data-color="white" data-speed ="1000" data-line-width="0.02" data-angle-steps=2  data-radial-size = "0.34">
</div>
```

Comment: IMO there is a lot wrong with your first paragraph. May I suggest you rewrite or remove it?

Comment: The statement that "canvas and javascript always win". The suggestion that SVG cannot be animated with JS. And IMO the statement "CSS and SVG ... limits design to the predefined (declared) rules " is a bit of a head-scratcher also.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau The next paragraph (in answer) clearly states that Javascript (JS) adds to the functionality. I do not see the inference "SVG cannot be animated with JS." . CSS and SVG (also HTML) are declarative languages within a very rigorous domain, this limits the possibilities, JS expands the possibilities with both SVG and JS benefiting, you are suggesting that SVG can do anything Javascript can. I have modified the paragraph and removed the " to the predefined (declared) rules" as it was just a explanatory coherence to "declarative language". and could be misconstrued.